# Cloudinary: Error in sending request to server-couldn't open file

Tags: php, cloudinary

In cloudinary php i have the required files and set my config too but when i try to upload a picture from php file

```
\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload("1.png");
```

**i get error**

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error in sending request to server - couldn't open file in C:\wamp\www\demo\src\Uploader.php on line 200
Exception: Error in sending request to server - couldn't open file "1.png" in C:\wamp\www\demo\src\Uploader.php on line 200
Call Stack
```

Answer (score 3):

The uploader cannot find the file you are trying to upload. Try to put the 1.png file in the same directory as the php file and run:

```
\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload(realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/1.png'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like 1.png is hardcoded somewhere and your parameter is not taken into account. Try to do a project wide search for 1.png and see if you can replace that with a parameter.

Comment: 1.png my image that im uploading. Its stored in the root directory itself.Even if i give a path of an image it gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

I might as well provide an answer here because I had the same exact problem, contacted Cloudinary's support team, and their solution worked.

First, I have an `images` folder and keep all of them there.

```
\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload('images/image1.jpg');
```

That caused the same error you got. I then changed it to:

```
\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\images\\image1.jpg");
```

That worked perfectly. However, I didn't want to use absolute paths, so that's why I contacted their support team. This is the code that works:

```
\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/test/images/image1.jpg");
```

The `test` value in that string is the directory of my site, inside the `htdocs` folder.